# C++ object memory layout when virtual inherit happend?

Tags: visual-c++

### compiled in VC6

```
class A 
{ 
    public: 
        int x; 
    public: 
        virtual void funA() { } 
}; 

class B : virtual public A 
{ 
    public: 
        int y; 
    public: 
        virtual void funA() { } 
        virtual void funB() { } 
}; 
sizeof(B)=20 // because of B::vptr+vbptr+B::y+A::vptr+A::x = 5*4
```

---

```
class A 
{ 
    public: 
        int x; 
    public: 
        virtual void funA() { } 
}; 

class B : virtual public A 
{ 
    public: 
        int y; 
    public: 
        B() {} 
        virtual void funB() { } 
}; 
sizeof(B)=20 // because of B::vptr+vbptr+B::y+A::vptr+A::x = 5*4
```

---

```
class A 
{ 
    public: 
        int x; 
    public: 
        virtual void funA() { } 
}; 

class B : virtual public A 
{ 
    public: 
        int y; 
    public: 
        B() {} 
        virtual void funA() { } 
        virtual void funB() { } 
}; 
sizeof(B)=24
```

i can't understand , why it's going to be 24???
i think they are the same!

Comment: What were the others compiled with?

Comment: Why should it be of any predefined size? The standard doesn't require any specific object size in this case.

Comment: Changed the tag to visual-c++. OP asks about an implementation detail, not about the language per se.

Comment: @Vlad: The question is, why does one particular ancient compiler happen to do something weird? It's perhaps a useful question for anyone still stuck with that compiler. The standard is irrelevant, since the compiler predates it.

Comment: @Mike: Well, everything that is not against standard shouldn't be so weird, right? Anyway, VC6 is considered to be quite buggy.

Comment: is the three calss memory layout different?
of course the C++ standard doesn't require any specific object size in this case, and i know gcc will be different with vc6.
but in this case, i think the three class allocate the same memory!!???????

Answer (score 0):

Based on a quick check of the memory after compilation it appears, that a 4 byte block/pad is being added in between the layouts of B and A only when B has a constructor.  I'm not sure of the reasoning, but if you are planing to copy memory around, I would recommend against it.

no B::B() // **class version 2**
const B::'vftable'{for 'B'}
const B::'vbtable'
y
const B::'vftable'{for 'A'}
x
size = 20

including B::B() // **class version 3**
const B::'vftable'{for 'B'}
const B::'vbtable'
y
*0x00000000 // 4 bytes*
const B::'vftable'{for 'A'}
x
size = 24